# CMake add_custom_command: How to write a "quoted string" to a file?

Tags: cmake

I have spent way too much time trying to add a custom command that writes a "quoted string" to a file:

```
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT file
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "\"quoted string\"" > file
    ...
    DEPENDS something
    VERBATIM (?)
)
```

I have tried various ways to escape the quotes `\"`, `\\"`, `\\\"`, quoting the whole command, putting the command in variable, but none of them worked. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works on both Windows(Ninja) and WSL(unix makefiles):

```
set(my_output what_it_is.txt)
add_custom_command(
        OUTPUT ${my_output}
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo \"quoted string\" > ${my_output}
        VERBATIM
)
```

And the output:

```
$ cat some_bin/what_it_is.txt
"quoted string"
```

In my limited experience, `VERBATIM` is usually the key if you're fighting escaping things in custom commands.

Note: I believe that the redirect is platform specific, so you might want to consider doing something like the [file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#writing) command in a CMake script and invoking that script in the custom command, `COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P some_script.cmake`.

Comment: Yes, that works, thanks! Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to scale to my actual use case. I ended up using some inline Python.